# Rails 4.1.6 Mailers Hanging

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, freeze, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I just upgraded to rails 4.1.6 with ruby 2.1.2.  None of my Mailers are working they are all hanging prior to, or perhaps during, rendering the templates.  If I downgrade to 4.1.5 mailers work perfectly.  From console If I break out of the hang using control-c this is the (important part) stack:

```
f = FooMailer.invite(FitnessClass.first, User.first, User.last)
FooMailer#invite: processed outbound mail in 94063.9ms
IRB::Abort: abort then interrupt!
from /Users/derrek/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mail-2.6.1/lib/mail/field_list.rb:22:in `call'
from /Users/derrek/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mail-2.6.1/lib/mail/field_list.rb:22:in `+'
from /Users/derrek/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mail-2.6.1/lib/mail/field_list.rb:22:in `+'
from /Users/derrek/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mail-2.6.1/lib/mail/field_list.rb:22:in `<<'
from /Users/derrek/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mail-2.6.1/lib/mail/header.rb:178:in `[]='
from /Users/derrek/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mail-2.6.1/lib/mail/message.rb:1309:in `[]='
from /Users/derrek/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionmailer-4.1.6/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:786:in `block in mail'
from /Users/derrek/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionmailer-4.1.6/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:786:in `each'
from /Users/derrek/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionmailer-4.1.6/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:786:in `mail'
from /Users/derrek/git/foo/foo/app/mailers/foo_mailer.rb:18:in `invite'
```

Comment: The commit referenced in the answers specifically mentions the ruby-units gem as being related.  Are you using that gem or is this bug independent of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep - it was an infinite loop in the Mail gem.  This has been fixed by [this commit](https://github.com/mikel/mail/commit/e3e1a4e2aace80d059bab6fa8189e4852e99adbb) and will be ok in version 2.6.2.  Until then:

```
gem 'mail', github: "mikel/mail"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem to be in the Mail gem. If I downgrade to 2.5.4 everything works again.  I didn't trace exactly what was going on but in version 2.6.1 the code was getting stuck in an infinite loop.  I'd say this is more a work a round than a fix, but it's better than being stuck.

```
gem 'mail', '2.5.4'
```